# iMac 27" late 2012 boots into Windows 7, but screen is white. How to activate screen?

Tags: windows, imac, screen

I've replaced the HDD in an iMac 27" late 2012, and image copied it to new one, and it doesn't seem to want to boot. I noticed it actually boots into Windows 7, but the physical screen is still white, yet I can connect and work normally via RDP.  I've tried to update nvidia drivers, several restarts, but no change.

I've done reset of PVRAM via

```
START + ALT + R + P
```

but no luck.  It looks like, as if it would have 2 screens, but there isn't a secondary one.
Hard disk is GPT formatted with 3 partitions made by Win 7 installation (EFI-boot, and 2 NTFS where are system and data)
Any clues?

Comment: Best guess is you didn't get the connections right when you re-assembled it. BTW, how did you 'image copy' to the new device?

Comment: no display works fine, as I booted macOS, and parted magic many times.  Image copy I've done via Parted Magic with help of another comp.  @Tetsujin

Comment: idk Parted Magic at all, but it doesn't appear to support APFS. I've no idea if it supports bootcamp, sorry. Please add all relevant detail to your question body & see if someone else can pick up on it.

Comment: There are no APFS partitions only FAT32 for EFI and  NTFS and disk is GPT.  And was working fine already.  It just must be some trick that either resolution isn't right or is displaying windows to different monitor (non-existing)

Comment: You need to add ***complete*** detail to your question, not as comments. macOS won't boot from FAT32 or NTFS...

Comment: This may be a Windows configuration problem, which is outside my scope to answer. As for resetting NVRAM, which may clear certain display settings, you mention the “Start” key, which suggests a Windows keyboard and thus won’t work. Do you have an Apple keyboard available?

Comment: I do not have apple keyboard available, but it did work resetting NVRAM, as it rebooted as I read online that it should 2x within 20s. Also suggestion to use WIN key I found online, and it looks it is same as using Command key @pion .  It's hard to say what is the problem, as same windows configuration worked fine on the same machine

Comment: Denis, your question and comments have many contradictions. For example, you say "I boot macOS", but "only FAT32 for EFI and NTFS". This is impossible. Both can not be true.

Comment: @DavidAnderson no contradictions.  I tried macOS and was working up to 10.15.7. Then I went back to Windows 7 as it was on originally (formatted SSD by copying image of old HDD)  Also Imac boots directly via Windows 7 installation USB, but not via Win 10 installation USB, unless made in normal MBR mode

Comment: OK. I thought all Windows 7 installations on Macs are suppose to BIOS boot. This means the drive needs to be MBR or Hybrid partitioned. You state the "disk is GPT". This seems to be wrong. If you have the installation media, then you should consider trying both Hybrid/BIOS and GPT/UEFI methods of booting. Does the installation media contain the [Windows Support Software (Boot Camp Support Software)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson  No Drive has to be GPT formated regardless if macOS or Windows, but this version of imac is not able to boot newer EFI boot USBs like Windows 10.  So what I ended up doing is was to copy Win 10 System partition over, then booted with Windows 7 install USB go to rescue mode to command prompt and formated EFI partition and install EFI system again (bcdboot c:\Winodows /f UEFI) and now Windows 10 is working fine.  However my original question is still puzzling me=> how is possible for the Windows 7 to boot normally yet display shows white screen?